# pointing selenium tests through nodePort in a service

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-service

I have this in a `selenium-hub-service.yml` file:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: selenium-srv
spec:
  selector:
    app: selenium-hub
  ports:
  - port: 4444
    nodePort: 30001
  type: NodePort
  sessionAffinity: None
```

When I do `kubectl describe service` on terminal, I get the endpoint of kubernetes service as `192.168.49.2:8443`. I then take that and point the browser to `192.168.49.2:30001` but browser is not able to reach that endpoint. I was expecting to reach selenium hub.

When I do `minikube service selenium-srv --url`, which gives me `http://127.0.0.1:56498` and point browser to it, I can reach the hub.

My question is: why am I not able to reach through `nodePort`?

I would like to do it through `nodePort` way because I know the port beforehand and if kubernetes service end point remains constant then it may be easy to point my tests to a known endpoint when I integrate it with azure pipeline.

EDIT: output of `kubectl get service`:

```
NAME           TYPE        CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
kubernetes     ClusterIP   10.96.0.1      <none>        443/TCP          4d
selenium-srv   NodePort    10.96.34.117   <none>        4444:30001/TCP   2d2h
```

Comment: Would you add o/p of `kubectl get svc` ?

Comment: I edited above to show that

Comment: Where did you setup your minikube cluster? Linux, Mac or Windows? Which [minikube driver](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/drivers/) did you use? If it is linux host, do you have interface like `br-42319e616ec5` with address `inet 192.168.49.1/24` ? (`ip a` command)? Are you able to ping `192.168.42.2` from your host?

Comment: I set it up on mac. I installed minikube through this `curl -LO https://storage.googleapis.com/minikube/releases/latest/minikube-darwin-amd64` . Request to `192.168.42.2` is timing out

Comment: Ok, thanks. Check [this topic on GitHub](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/11193) - seems on Mac you can only use localhost address to access services. Is it OK for you?

Comment: I was able to access on `http://127.0.0.1:62051`  when I run `minikube service selenium-srv` . I was wondering what was missing accessing on `192.168.49.2:30001`

Answer (score 1):

Posted community wiki based on [this Github topic](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/11193). Feel free to expand it.

The information below assumes that you are using [the default driver docker](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/drivers/docker/).

---

Minikube on macOS behaves a bit differently than on Linux. While on Linux, you have special interfaces used for docker and for connecting to the minikube node port, like this one:

```
3: docker0:
...
inet 172.17.0.1/16
```

And this one:

```
4: br-42319e616ec5:
...
inet 192.168.49.1/24 brd 192.168.49.255 scope global br-42319e616ec5
```

There is no such solution implemented on macOS. [Check this](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/11193#issuecomment-826331511):

> This is a known issue, Docker Desktop networking doesn't support ports. You will have to use minikube tunnel.

[Also](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/11193#issuecomment-826708118):

> there is no bridge0 on Macos, and it makes container IP unreachable from host.

That means you can't connect to your service using IP address `192.168.49.2`.

Check also this article: [Known limitations, use cases, and workarounds - Docker Desktop for Mac](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/mac/networking/#known-limitations-use-cases-and-workarounds):

> **There is no docker0 bridge on macOS**
> Because of the way networking is implemented in Docker Desktop for Mac, you cannot see a  `docker0`  interface on the host. This interface is actually within the virtual machine.

> **I cannot ping my containers**
> Docker Desktop for Mac can’t route traffic to containers.

> **Per-container IP addressing is not possible**
> The docker (Linux) bridge network is not reachable from the macOS host.

There are few ways to [setup minikube to use NodePort at the localhost address on Mac, like this one](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/11193#issuecomment-826708118):

```
minikube start --driver=docker --extra-config=apiserver.service-node-port-range=32760-32767 --ports=127.0.0.1:32760-32767:32760-32767`
```

You can also use `minikube service` command which will return a URL to connect to a service.

Answer (score 0):

is your deployment running on port **4444** ?

try this

**deployment.yaml**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: selenium-hub
  labels:
    app: selenium-hub
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: selenium-hub
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: selenium-hub
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: selenium-hub
        image: selenium/hub:3.141
        ports:
          - containerPort: 4444
        resources:
          limits:
            memory: "1000Mi"
            cpu: ".5"
        livenessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /wd/hub/status
            port: 4444
          initialDelaySeconds: 30
          timeoutSeconds: 5
        readinessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /wd/hub/status
            port: 4444
          initialDelaySeconds: 30
          timeoutSeconds: 5
```

**service.yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: selenium-hub
  labels:
    app: selenium-hub
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 4444
    targetPort: 4444
    name: port0
  selector:
    app: selenium-hub
  type: NodePort
  sessionAffinity: None
```

if you want to use to chrome

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: selenium-node-chrome
  labels:
    app: selenium-node-chrome
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: selenium-node-chrome
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: selenium-node-chrome
    spec:
      volumes:
      - name: dshm
        emptyDir:
          medium: Memory
      containers:
      - name: selenium-node-chrome
        image: selenium/node-chrome-debug:3.141
        ports:
          - containerPort: 5555
        volumeMounts:
          - mountPath: /dev/shm
            name: dshm
        env:
          - name: HUB_HOST
            value: "selenium-hub"
          - name: HUB_PORT
            value: "4444"
```

testing python code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

def check_browser(browser):
  driver = webdriver.Remote(
    command_executor='http://<IP>:<PORT>/wd/hub',
    desired_capabilities=getattr(DesiredCapabilities, browser)
  )
  driver.get("http://google.com")
  assert "google" in driver.page_source
  driver.quit()
  print("Browser %s checks out!" % browser)

check_browser("CHROME")
```